# C# Не отображаются проценты при загрузке файла с FTP

Tags: c#

Есть код:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
    {
        int Per = e.ProgressPercentage;
        Console.Write(Per);
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
    };
webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) => { };
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("awersome.adress"), @"awersome.path");
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

По идее он должен выводить на консоль проценты загрузки. Однако вместо этого он выводит ноль постоянно, и при завершении 100. Что тут не так?
Выводил на консоль и по другому, выводил в файл. Все равно результат такой-же.
Использовался и такой код, в этом случае просто нули идут, без 100 в конце.

```
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) = > {
    if (Monitor.TryEnter(webClient))
    {
        try
        {
            int Per = e.ProgressPercentage;
            Console.Write(Per);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(webClient);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: А что за файл,который вы скачиваете? Дайте полный пример потестить. С тестовым файлом у меня все работает...

Comment: А какой размер у файла на котором вы тестируете?

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко Разное тэстировал. Был и файл с 200метров, был и со 100, был с 80 и 12.

Comment: Чтобы знать проценты -- нужно знать полный размер файла, а его сервер не отдаёт.

Comment: Рекомендую как разберётесь -- удалить комментарий с реальным url чтобы не светить логины/пароли.

Comment: @AK В любом случае -  этот логин с паролем дают доступ только для чтения, а ничего секретного там нету.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Почитаем MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged.aspx):

> Передача файла пассивный FTP будет показывать процент выполнения,
>   равное нулю, так как сервер не передает размер файла. Для отображения
>   хода выполнения, можно изменить FTP-соединение на "Активно",
>   переопределив `GetWebRequest` виртуальный метод:
>
> ```
> internal class MyWebClient:WebClient
> {
>     protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address) {
>         FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
>         req.UsePassive = false;
>         return req;
>     }
> }
> ```

Но у меня, к сожалению, не получилось сделать это рабочим. Поэтому могу предложить первым реквестом вытянуть размер файла и при каждом срабатывании ивента вычислять процент:

```
var uriString = @"ftp://user:password@server/usb1_4/minecraft/DontTouchThisFolder/OC.jar";
long totalBytes;
var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriString);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    totalBytes = response.ContentLength;
}

var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.BytesReceived * 100 / totalBytes);
};
webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) => { };
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(uriString), @"D:/1.bin");
```

Comment: [Активный режим ftp требует входящих соединений](http://sys-adm.org.ua/system/ftp-nat), они могут быть заблокированы firewall'ом.

Comment: Здравствуйте, может вы сможете подсказать по моей похожей проблеме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/795261/c-ftp-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8

Answer (score 3):

Ftp-сервер не отдаёт полный размер файла, см. [Download file from FTP with Progress - TotalBytesToReceive is always -1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591059/download-file-from-ftp-with-progress-totalbytestoreceive-is-always-1)

У вас при детальном анализе на консоль выводится:

> ```
> Downloaded 8192 of -1
> Downloaded 16384 of -1
> Downloaded 24576 of -1
> Downloaded 32768 of -1
> Downloaded 40960 of -1
> Downloaded 49152 of -1
> Downloaded 57344 of -1
> Downloaded 65536 of -1
> Downloaded 73728 of -1
> Downloaded 81920 of -1
> Downloaded 90112 of -1
> Downloaded 98304 of -1
> Downloaded 106496 of -1
> ...
> Downloaded 12566528 of -1
> Downloaded 12574720 of -1
> Downloaded 12582912 of -1
> Downloaded 12584573 of -1
> Downloaded 12584573 of 12584573
> Completed
> ```

PS Полностью код примера:

```
void Main()
{
    var url = "ftp://user:password@server/usb1_4/minecraft/DontTouchThisFolder/OC.jar";
    var path = @"C:\downloads\123.test.zip";
    StartDownload(url, path);
}

private void StartDownload(string url, string path)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), path);
}

void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
    double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
    double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
    var text = "Downloaded " + e.BytesReceived + " of " + e.TotalBytesToReceive;
    Console.WriteLine(text);
    //progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
}

void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Completed");
}
```

Хотел привести полностью пример из вопроса на en-so, который я приводил выше, но пока меня отвлекли по работе -- уже AGS17 написал итоговый код, так что рекомендую поставить галку на его ответе.