# C# Неконтролируемое обновление консольного прогрессбара

Tags: c#

В предыдущем вопросе, [C# Не отображаются проценты при загрузке файла с FTP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/686955/c-%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0#686955) , мне подсказали данный код. Он работает, однако, я не могу использовать мой прогресс бар. Как я понял, ***webClient.DownloadProgressChanged*** выполняется при каждом обновлении, то есть очень быстро и с рандомной частотой. Однако, бывают случаи, когда скрипт еще не успел отработать и по верх него накладывается еще один. Таким образом у меня срывает прогресс бар и появляются лишние символы, которых там быть не должно.
***Сам вопрос:*** как мне либо вывести переменную **percent** выше, в метод Main (что бы оттуда был доступ к ней), либо как мне сделать так, что бы код, находящийся в **webClient.DownloadProgressChanged** выполнялся не при каждом обновлении скачиваемого файла, а раз, допустим, в 1 секунду?

```
static void Main()
{
var uriString = @"ftp://user:password@server/Awersome.file";
long totalBytes;
var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriString);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
totalBytes = response.ContentLength;
}

var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
{
int percent = (e.BytesReceived * 100 / totalBytes);
//другой код
};
webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) => { };
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(uriString), @"D:/1.bin");
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472205/c-sharp-event-debounce

Comment: `Console.Write(value + "\r")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот ещё пример с Reactive Extensions. (Они особенно хороши, когда нужно получить контроль над потоками данных, которыми кто-то «бросается» в вас неудобным образом.) Самое сложное в нём — сконвертировать event в `IObservable`.

```
async Task DownloadWithConsoleOutput(Uri uri, string savePath)
{
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        // все сообщения о прогрессе
        var allEvents = Observable.FromEventPattern<DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler,
                                                    DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs>(
                            h => wc.DownloadProgressChanged += h,
                            h => wc.DownloadProgressChanged -= h)
                .Select(p => p.EventArgs);
        var debouncedEvents = allEvents.Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)) // не чаще раза в
                                       .DistinctUntilChanged(); // секунду и без повторов
        // для UI-программ скорее всего понадобится ещё .ObserveOnDispatcher();
        // подписываемся на последовательность
        using (debouncedEvents.Subscribe(args =>
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"Received: {args.BytesReceived} bytes, {args.ProgressPercentage}%")))
        {
            // запускаем загрузку и дожидаемся окончания
            await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(uri, path);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Download finished");
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, тоже работает, спасибо.

Comment: @SKProCH: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3):

```
int previousPercent = 0;
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
{
  int percent = (e.BytesReceived * 100 / totalBytes);
  if (percent > previousPercent)
  {
    //другой код
    previousPercent = percent;
  }
};
```

Comment: Да, отчасти помогло. Однако, можно это сделать ещё и по времени?

Comment: @SKProCH можно, конечно. Заведите `DateTime lastTime = DateTime.Now;` рядом с `previousPercent `, и добавьте в `if` условие `(last.AddSeconds(3) < DateTime.Now)`.

Comment: `(lastTime.AddSeconds(3) < DateTime.Now)` - `Time` пропустил

Comment: Я уже и сам исправил. Спасибо.

Comment: @VladD, предложите решение на `reactive extensions`?

Comment: @Андрей: Готово!